# Is it possible to be notified of SLComposeViewController text changes

Tags: ios, slcomposeviewcontroller

I've got a few SLComposeViewControllers in a feature in our app, and we are trying to add analytics to this feature.

What we are trying to do is track if a user changed the text inside of the `SLComposeViewController` before hitting the "post" button. I've been searching for a way, and the only way I found was to loop through the subviews of `SLComposeViewController`, however that seems to hit way too many snags to be an acceptable way to go about this issue.

Are there any other ways we could be notified of any changes in the text of `SLComposeViewController`? Or am I out of luck on trying to do this in a stable way?

Comment: hello, did you find a solution Bill? Looking for a solution :)

Comment: How did you manage to do that by looping through subviews? I can't get the UITextView by looping, I only get UISizeTrackingView and UIRemoteView. The latter has no subviews.